# SqlAlchemy query / merging rows

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have to search for rows in a table and merge them and teir values.

Example:

```
id_sender id_receiver nb_mails
    3           4         10
    1           2         13
    4           3          5
```

so i want to get a resultat like this:

```
id_1 id_2 nb_communication
 3     4      15
 1     2      13
```

Is it possible to be done with sqlalchemy or i need to do my own treatment ?

Solved with :

```
q = session.query(
                  label('id_1' ,func.least(table.initiator_id, table.receiver_id)), 
                  label('id_2', func.greatest(table.initiator_id, table.receiver_id)), 
                  label('nb_communication', func.sum(table.nb_mails)) 
                 ).order_by("nb_communication").group_by('id_1', 'id_2').all()
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: More often than not if it is doable in SQL, it is doable in SQLAlchemy. Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes tried this thing and it did my job:

q = session.query(
        label('id_1' ,func.least(table.initiator_id, table.receiver_id)),
        label('id_2', func.greatest(table.initiator_id, table.receiver_id)),
        label('nb_communication', func.count(table.nb_mails))
    ).order_by("nb_communication").group_by('id_1', 'id_2').all()

Comment: Are you sure about that `func.count(table.nb_mails)`? Should it be `func.sum()`?

Comment: edited the func.count() to func.sum()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support the `least()` and `greatest()` functions.  You can do:

```
select least(id_sender, id_receiver) as id_1,
       greatest(id_sender, id_receiver) as id_2,
       sum(nb_mails) as nb_communication
from t
group by least(id_sender, id_receiver),
         greatest(id_sender, id_receiver);
```

If your database doesn't support these functions, you can do something similar using `case`.

Comment: thanks that helped me to find an idea to solve my problem in sqlalchemy